# Firebase Messaging: app/network-timeout (Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase's admin SDK on a node JS server.
I've noticed that regularly a whole batch of notifications fails with no apparent reason. It works fine most of the time, and hop, one of a sudden, 20 notifications in a row show a timeout.

The full error message is:

```
{
  code: "app/network-timeout",
  message: "Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded."
}
```

The code i'm using summed up:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: [...],
  databaseURL: 'https://[...].firebaseio.com'
});

const message = {
  notification: {
    title: "My title",
    body: "My content"
  },
  token: token
}

admin.messaging().send(message)
    .then((response) => {
      // message sent with success (most of the time)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // message error: timeout
    })
```

I thought maybe it's related with the pricing plan as I usually  had those kind of failure using limited features of firebase, but messaging is showing as "FREE" in the pricing plan. I switched to spark anyway in case, I will monitor for any change.

I couldn't find anyone reporting such issue, any idea why I *randomly* timeout using **Firebase Messaging** ?

Comment: Are you trying to send large volumes of messages at the same time? It might be taxing the Node.js process causing some operations to get queued up and timeout. Also if you're using v8.2.0 or higher, the SDK also retries ETIMEDOUT errors about 4 times before throwing an error. Make sure you're using a recent version.

Comment: did you solve it ? i got same issue here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message is suggesting to me that your server was temporarily unable to reach FCM servers.  It's saying that the timeout of 10 seconds was exceeded.  If you reach this error message, you should retry the API to send the message.

Network problems do occur from time to time, and there are probably a dozen network hops between your server and Firebase that you don't control.  Retries on network failure is always important for fault tolerance.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to check if there was another possibility than server/network reliability issues, thank you, I will reschedule the notifications that time out.

Comment: So what can we do about it?